# Accordian Jquery - Toggle Button implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a jquery accordian menu project that I built on the jquery website.

In the accordian menu I have an iframe. I want to toggle between 2 iframes in this menu. So outside of the iframe that is shown on load for first time. I would like to show a toggle button , on clicking which it will take me to a new iframe. Again on click of this iframe it must take me back to the default page.

Please find the project in this link : https://app.box.com/s/vmkhhxcq4gfji2hxwtwx

Kindly help me build a working toggle button below the iframe to toggle between the default src and a new src.

HTML ->

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="css/BlueTheme/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
    <script>
               $(function() {

            $( "#accordion" ).accordion();

            $( "#dialog-link, #icons li" ).hover(
            function() {
                $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-hover" );
            },
            function() {
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-hover" );
            }
        );
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        body{
            font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        .demoHeaders {
            margin-top: 2em;
        }
        #dialog-link {
            padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;
            text-decoration: none;
            position: relative;
        }
        #dialog-link span.ui-icon {
            margin: 0 5px 0 0;
            position: absolute;
            left: .2em;
            top: 50%;
            margin-top: -8px;
        }
        #icons {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #icons li {
            margin: 2px;
            position: relative;
            padding: 4px 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            float: left;
            list-style: none;
        }
        #icons span.ui-icon {
            float: left;
            margin: 0 4px;
        }
        .fakewindowcontain .ui-widget-overlay {
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
     </head>
      <body>
       <div class="wrap">
        <div class="absolute">
            <div id="accordion">

                <h3>Sample Iframe</h3>
                <div class="iframe"><div><iframe src="www.google.com" frameborder="0"    scrolling="no" width="370"></iframe></div></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the html..trying this link : http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/AvEqM/

How to get it to work ?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code here. That link requires credentials.

Comment: Sorry about that...https://app.box.com/s/vmkhhxcq4gfji2hxwtwx..can you please check now

Comment: Just post your code in the question. That link still doesn't work. People are more likely to read your question with the code included.

Comment: Link works fine now..I have also posted the code Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to change this from a two button system to a single toggle button. If that is correct, try this.

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/Zfq7v/" width="100%" height="600px"></iframe>
<button id="one">toggle</button>

<script>
var buttonOne = document.getElementById("one");
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
//need a variable to keep track of the active element
var active = 1;

buttonOne.addEventListener("click", buttonClick, false);

function buttonClick(e){
    if(active === 2){
        iframe.src = "http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/Zfq7v/";
        active = 1;
    }else{
        iframe.src = "http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/u73rF/";
        active = 2;
    } 
};
</script>
```

Comment: I am not able to get the button working too...can you please integrate the same in the project and help me get it to work ?